# the result of mongo export is not a valid json

Tags: mongodb

I use this command to export data from db, but it not a valid json, it doesn't have comma at the end of item, how to fix this issue?

https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoexport/#syntax

```
  {
    "id" : "1",
    "name" : "a"
  }
  {
    "id" : "2",
    "name" : "b"
  }
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "c"
  }
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "d"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the --jsonArray option (see https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoexport/#std-option-mongoexport.--jsonArray )

```
mongoexport --quiet -d test -c test --pretty --jsonArray
[{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "611aca090848cb8cab2943f7"
    },
    "id": "1",
    "name": "a"
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "611aca110848cb8cab2943f8"
    },
    "id": "2",
    "name": "b"
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "611aca180848cb8cab2943f9"
    },
    "id": "3",
    "name": "c"
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "611aca1d0848cb8cab2943fa"
    },
    "id": "4",
    "name": "d"
}]
```